# Доступ до frame (not iframe) с помощью jQuery

Tags: javascript

Есть index.html с двумя frame.

```
<frameset rows="50%, 50%">
        <frame id="frame1" src="frame1.html" />
        <frame id="frame2"  src="frame2.html" />
</frameset>
```

Есть frame1.html c таким кодом:

```
   <body id="bodytest">
frame1 show
   </body>
```

Пытаюсь делать так.

```
$('#bodytest',top.frames["frame1"].document).append("<div>yes,div</div>");
```

Я хочу достучаться до body и добавить div. Как это можно сделать?

Как можно прослушивать события, например нажатии button во frame, а реагировать в parent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<frameset rows="50%, 50%">
 <frame name="frame_A" src="frA.html">
 <frame name="frame_B" src="frB.html">
</frameset>
```

frA.html:

```
<button onclick="parent.frame_B.document.write('Hello, another World!);">Кнопащка</button>
```

Когда вы работаете с фреймами, ваш код работает В КОНТЕКСТЕ ФРЕЙМА, в котором он написан. Чтобы залезть из одного фрейма в другой, вам нужно:
Пойти в родителя - окно браузера (`parent`) (чем глубже вложенность - тем больше парентов)
Выбрать фрейм по имени (`parent.frameName`) и дальше делать то, что вы хотели. Варианта на jQuery не встречал и не знаю - отказался от фреймов раньше, чем начал изучать jQuery.

Comment: А как сделать обратное? При нажатии кнопочки во frame переменная передается в parent? Возможно ли повесить обработчик из parent?

Comment: А зачем вам ее передавать в родителя, если в нем - лишь 2 фрейма?

Comment: Вы можете либо из одного фрейма изменять другой, либо в одном фрейме прослушивать какие-нибудь события в другом

Comment: > либо в одном фрейме прослушивать какие-нибудь события в другом >>> можете код скинуть как это сделать? заранее спасибо

Comment: Попробуйте так, вдруг сработает: `$('#button_id', window.frames['frB'].document).click($('div_id_in_frA').html('The button in frB has been pressed. This event has been captured from the frA'));` здесь в первом селекторе после него вторым аргументом идет контекст - другой фрейм. Правда я не до конца понял, селекция в данном случае идет по id фрейма или по имени. В любом случае можно использовать порядковый номер.